# Lead-Acid Battery Desulfation Circuit Design:

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I'm seeking ideas for making a pulsing lead-acid desulfation circuit design.  Several circuit designs are available via Google image search, however, I'm hoping to get some help here to design a circuit with the following characteristics that is reliable & inexpensive:

1. Input:  120V AC @ 60 Hz
2. Output Pulses:  22-28 kHz, 250mA peak amplitude, pulse rise time < 1 µS

**Note:**  The output pulsed waveform should be like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the peak voltage on those pulses?  How negative do they go?  How much control over the downslope or pulse width do you need?

Comment: This question is horribly vague, but I've favorited in hopes of learning something first-hand about this technique.

Comment: That looks like the output current waveform of a flyback running in DCM or Crit ? ,Boundary , transition , S Trap .Your power is low so flyback could be the way to go .I  dont like your waveform and are concerned about EMC.

Comment: I was thinking it would be similar to these designs (but for personal use):  design 1 -  http://www.google.com/patents/US5063341 OR with elements of design 2 -  http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20090085526

Comment: @William Brodie-Tyrrell - I'm guessing the peak V < 17mV. Pulse width is < 2.5 µS? One of the above links shows "the triangular waveform has a linear rise time of approximately 412 million V/sec" AND "the triangular waveform has a linear fall time of approximately 40 million V/sec." The 2nd design also shows "the triangular waveform has a frequency between 30 KHz and 50 KHz" Also, the signals may not have to go negative.

Comment: @Daniel - what EMC effects concern you? Do you expect there to be an RF signal of significant power generated or something else?

Comment: Wrong guy. I don't really understand @Autistic 's comment.

Comment: @Daniel - Opps.. Sorry!

Comment: @Autistic - what EMC effects concern you? Do you expect there to be an RF signal of significant power generated or something else?

Comment: 400V/usec is a huge slew-rate and will require you have both a very low-impedance source and low-inductance cabling everywhere to be able to achieve that at the battery terminals.  You absolutely should be concerned about radiated emissions; this thing looks a lot like a broadband jammer.

Comment: And surely you mean 17V (for 12V battery) not 17mV...

Comment: @William Brodie-Tyrrell - It's not 400V/µS--it's 412V/Sec--which works out to ~16mV/pulse when one uses a rate of 25k pulses/S.  To your other question--I see some designs go as high has 50V, but, others are very low V as I specified earlier. Did you view the content of the urls that I provided above?

Comment: I think your question is unclear on this point. What is the peak voltage of the output waveform?

Comment: @Daniel - It is unclear.  That's the whole idea in seeking ideas here.  I've seen several designs with various peak voltages & I was hoping this type of question along with the content at the urls that I posted would stimulate some discussion.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like that is happening thus far.

Comment: Why such fast rising voltage reaching to any unknown peak is believed will desulfate lead acid battery? Sharply rising voltage will generate sharp current that will punch thru the sulfate compound?

Comment: @soosai steven - I don't know for certain & I haven't tested any of the designs to know how well any of them perform.  I was hoping this question would generate a dialog on the best design to use, but it appears few people are interested in this subject thus far.  My personal hypothesis is that the sharp power pulse acts as a shock, while the sloped part of the pulse serves to weaken the bonds more gradually.  The large number of repeated pulses per second is also obviously important due to each pulse providing more of the same affect.

Comment: I did not follow the links. But the quoted text says "412 million V/sec." That actually is 412 V/usec. Also, it is not clear if you want current pulses (250 mA apmplitude) or Voltage pulses. You cannot specify both. Usually you specify either the current or the voltage and let the load set the other variable. I would think that the current pulse would need to be scaled with battery capacity rather than fixed at a single number.

Comment: @mkeith - Ok, I see your point about the 412 V/µS.  Either way of writing it, there are ~25k pulses/S which works out to ~16.5 mV/pulse as I stated earlier.  Regarding the amplitude--I think it is a V amplitude.